# Passing int list as a parameter to a web user control

Tags: c#, asp.net, typeconverter

I want to pass an int list (List) as a declarative property to a web user control like this:

```
<UC:MyControl runat="server" ModuleIds="1,2,3" />
```

I created a TypeConverter to do this:

```
public class IntListConverter : System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvertFrom(
           System.ComponentModel.ITypeDescriptorContext context, 
           Type sourceType)
    {
        if (sourceType == typeof(string)) return true;
        return base.CanConvertFrom(context, sourceType);
    }
    public override object ConvertFrom(
      System.ComponentModel.ITypeDescriptorContext context, 
      System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, object value)
    {
        if (value is string)
        {
            string[] v = ((string)value).Split(
                new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            List<int> list = new List<int>();
            foreach (string s in vals)
            {
                list.Add(Convert.ToInt32(s));
            }
            return list
        }
        return base.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value);
    }
    public override bool CanConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context,
      Type destinationType)
    {
        if (destinationType == typeof(InstanceDescriptor)) return true;
        return base.CanConvertTo(context, destinationType);
    }
    public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context,
      System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
    {
        if (destinationType == typeof(InstanceDescriptor) && value is List<int>)
        {
            List<int> list = (List<int>)value;
            ConstructorInfo construcor = typeof(List<int>).GetConstructor(new Type[] { typeof(IEnumerable<int>) });
            InstanceDescriptor id = new InstanceDescriptor(construcor, new object[] { list.ToArray() });
            return id;
        }
        return base.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType);
    }
}
```

And then added the attribute to my property:

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(IntListConverter))]
public List<int> ModuleIds
{
    get { ... }; set { ... };
}
```

But I get this error at runtime:

`Unable to generate code for a value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List'1[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]'. This error occurred while trying to generate the property value for ModuleIds.`

My question is similar to one found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116797/passing-int-array-as-parameter-in-web-user-control), but the solution does not solve my problem:

**Update:** I found a page which solved the first problem.  I updated the code above to show my fixes.  The added code is the `CanConvertTo` and `ConvertTo` methods.  Now I get a different error.:

`Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

This error seems to be indirectly caused by something in the `ConvertTo` method.

Comment: Surely you didn't write IntListConverter in the class name and IntegerListConverter in the attribute, did you?

Comment: Ha, no... I'll fix that.

Comment: Thank you for asking this question. I faced nearly the same problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After hooking a debugger into Cassini, I see that the null ref is actually coming from System.Web.Compilation.CodeDomUtility.GenerateExpressionForValue, which is basically trying to get an expression for the int[] array you pass into the List constructor. Since there's no type descriptor for the int[] array, it fails (and throws a null ref in the process, instead of the "can't generate property set exception" that it should).

I can't figure out a built in way of getting a serializable value into a List<int>, so I just used a static method:

```
class IntListConverter : TypeConverter {
    public static List<int> FromString(string value) {
       return new List<int>(
          value
           .Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
           .Select(s => Convert.ToInt32(s))
       );
    }

    public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType) {
        if (destinationType == typeof(InstanceDescriptor)) {
            List<int> list = (List<int>)value;
            return new InstanceDescriptor(this.GetType().GetMethod("FromString"),
                new object[] { string.Join(",", list.Select(i => i.ToString()).ToArray()) }
            );
        }
        return base.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 For this answer as well. A working fix to a very obscure problem. I had the same issue as the OP other than using a `List<string>` instead of `List<int>`. Solution worked perfectly with a few minor changes to account for string vs. int.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Now I understand: The page builder is able to emit a "1,2,3" expression but can't emit a new List<string>{"1","2","3"} expression. Is there a way to instruct the builder to emit such an expression?

Comment: I didn't like the idea of writing the value as a string like "1,2,3" in the generated control class file because it will be deserialized on each request, so I wrote a ControlBuilder for my expression to initialize the collection then adds every value by calling the Add method

Answer (score 1):

pass the list from the code behind...

aspx:

```
<UC:MyControl id="uc" runat="server" />
```

code-behind:

```
List<int> list = new List<int>();
list.add(1);
list.add(2);
list.add(3);

uc.ModuleIds = list;
```

Comment: This is the workaround I've been using, but definitely less than optimal.

Comment: To me, this looks way better than the Type converter class. Which one is more readable?

Comment: The problem with this is it requires modifications to the code behind, which breaks the separation of declarative and non-declarative parts of the code.

Answer (score 1):

WHile I can't say I have any particular experience with this error, other sources indicate that you need to add a conversion to the type InstanceDescriptor.  check out:

http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2005/04/28/405013.aspx

Which provides an explanation of the reasons or alternatively:

http://forums.asp.net/p/1191839/2052438.aspx#2052438

Which provides example code similar to yours.

Comment: This seems to be the right direction, but I'm still getting an error.  See my update.

Answer (score 1):

I solved something simular by creating 2 properties:

```
public List<int> ModuleIDs { get .... set ... }
public string ModuleIDstring { get ... set ... }
```

The ModuleIDstring converts its value set to a list and sets the ModuleIDs property.

This will also make the ModuleIDs usable from a PropertyGrid etc.

Ok, not the best, typesafe solution, but for me it works.

Comment: This is probably the solution we will end up going with, but it is still strange that we can't figure out how to fix the actual error.

Answer (score 0):

The way I normally do this is to make the property wrap the ViewState collection. Your way looks better if it can be made to work, but this will get the job done:

```
public IList<int> ModuleIds
{
   get
   {
       string moduleIds = Convert.ToString(ViewState["ModuleIds"])

       IList<int> list = new Collection<int>();

       foreach(string moduleId in moduleIds.split(","))
       {
          list.Add(Convert.ToInt32(moduleId));
       }

      return list;
   }
}
```

Comment: Interesting idea, but still not optimal, as it would not allow declarative markup to work.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is the set{}.  The type converter want to change the `List<int>` back into a string, but `CanConvertFrom()` fails for `List<int>`.

Comment: No, that case is handled by a ConvertTo method, which is not shown, for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass it into a string and split on comma to populate a private variable. Does not have the nicety of attribution, but will work.

```
private List<int> modules;
public string ModuleIds
{
  set{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
    {
    if (modules == null) modules = new List<int>();
    var ids = value.Split(new []{','});
    if (ids.Length>0)
      foreach (var id in ids)
        modules.Add((int.Parse(id)));
    }
}
```

Comment: This is possible, but does not solve the problem.  What I am trying to do should be possible, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you're best option is to make your usercontrol have a DataSource-style property.

You take the property as an object and then do some type checking against IList/ IEnumerable/ etc to make sure that it is correct.