# Anything similar to WPF's ValueConverters for ASP.Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, valueconverter

After doing a project with WPF and getting very much attached to it's excellent databinding capabilities, I have now moved back to ASP.Net and am starting to miss some of WPF's stuff.

My question is...**is there anything similar to WPF's ValueConverters for ASP.Net**?

For example, I want a UserControl to expose a public property which is an `IEnumerable<int>` and the user can enter such from the source:

```
<asp:MyControl1 runat="server" ID="something" TheList="1,3,5,7"/>
```

And then the value in `TheList` will be converted to an `IEnumerable<int>`, with something like a ValueConverter of WPF's.

**[Update] Solution**

Thanks to [Nathan Baulch's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108328/anything-similar-to-wpfs-valueconverters-for-asp-net/1108420#1108420) mention of a [`TypeConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typeconverter.aspx), I got across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251439/passing-int-list-as-a-parameter-to-a-web-user-control) and I managed to build a string to list converter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you take a look at [System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typeconverter.aspx).

[This](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/TypeConverters.aspx) article on CodeProject includes an example that is quite similar to yours involving latitude and longitude strings.

Answer (score 0):

I think not. My best guess is implicit conversion from String to IEnumberable, which in general is a very bad thing, but would work in your case.

Everything in the markup is always treated as String, unless put in `<% %>` - then it is being interpreted.

What else you could do is to define IEnumerable DataSource control. Then MyControl would have TheListDataSourceID from where it will take the IEnumerable data.

```
<asp:MyControl1 runat="server" ID="something" TheListDataSourceID="myDataSource" />

<asp:MyIEnumerableDataSource runat="server" ID="myDataSource" TheList="1,3,5,7" />
```

Then the IEnumerableDataSource would do the conversion and would return IEnumerable for the user control wanting it. Much better case than the implicit conversion.