# How to create InstanceDescriptor for List of enum?

Tags: c#, asp.net, custom-controls, typeconverter, typedescriptor

Similar question: [Passing int list as a parameter to a web user control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251439/passing-int-list-as-a-parameter-to-a-web-user-control)

Is there any similar example for enum type?

I am creating a asp.net custom control in which I want to pass comma separated list of enums as property.
I am writing a `TypeConverter` for converting comma separated string values to List of Enum.

In the `ConvertTo` method,
How to create `InstanceDescriptor` object for list of enum?

My current code is as follows:

```
//enum
public enum MyEnum {Hello, World}

//main method
List<MyEnum> list = new List<MyEnum>();
list.Add(MyEnum.Hello);
list.Add(MyEnum.World);
ConstructorInfo constructor = typeof(List<MyEnum>).GetConstructor( Type.EmptyTypes );
InstanceDescriptor idesc = new InstanceDescriptor(constructor, list);
```

This fails with the message

```
Length mismatch
```

I wonder why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Length mismatch" error occurs because you retrieve the [default `List<T>` constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4kf43ys3(v=vs.110).aspx), which has **ZERO** arguments, and then you ask `InstanceDescriptor` to call that constructor with **TWO** arguments, `MyEnum.Hello` and `MyEnum.World`.

You might think that you could use the [alternate `List<T>` constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkbw11z0(v=vs.110).aspx) that accepts a single `IEnumerable<T>` argument:

```
ConstructorInfo constructor =
    typeof(List<MyEnum>).GetConstructor(new[] { typeof(IEnumerable<MyEnum>) });
InstanceDescriptor idesc = new InstanceDescriptor(constructor, new[] { list });
```

This makes `InstanceDescriptor` happy, but unfortunately, you'll find that ASP.NET now throws `NullReferenceException` instead (same as in the [question you linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251439/passing-int-list-as-a-parameter-to-a-web-user-control)) because ASP.NET doesn't know how to deal with `IEnumerable<T>` parameters.

Here are two ways to solve the problem.

**Solution 1:** Change your custom control and your type converter to use `MyEnum[]` instead of `List<MyEnum>`. This works because ASP.NET can handle arrays.

**Solution 2:** Create a static helper method that creates a `List<MyEnum>` from an array:

```
public static List<MyEnum> ToList(MyEnum[] values)
{
    return new List<MyEnum>(values);
}
```

Then change your type converter to create an `InstanceDescriptor` that calls the helper method, passing it your list as an array:

```
MethodInfo method = typeof(MyEnumListConverter).GetMethod("ToList");
InstanceDescriptor idesc = new InstanceDescriptor(method, new[] { list.ToArray() });
```

Answer (score 2):

Your list should be an empty collection because `constructor` is the parameterless `constructor` your code should look like this:

```
List<MyEnum> list = new List<MyEnum>();
ConstructorInfo constructor = typeof(List<MyEnum>).GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);
InstanceDescriptor idesc = new InstanceDescriptor(constructor, list);
```

Or use a null `constructor`:

```
ConstructorInfo constructor = 
  typeof(List<MyEnum>).GetConstructor(BindingFlags.ExactBinding, null,Type.EmptyTypes, null);
```

That means:  the `EmptyTypes` field used in one of the `GetConstructor` methods to get a `constructor` that takes no parameters.

Comment: this returns null `constructor` object