# Cannot create an object of type 'System.String[]' from its string representation '[1,2]'

Tags: asp.net, custom-controls

I need an ASP.Net control on your property you can specify an array type string. That is, in my ASP.Net control would have something like:

```
DefaultValue("")> Category("Misc"), <Bindable(True),
Public Overridable Property MyProperty () As String ()
   Get
      Return mMyProperty
   End Get
   Set (ByVal value As String ())
     mMyProperty = value
   End Set
End Property
```

And from the ASP.Net page I need to pass the values​​, type:

```
<WC:MyControl MyProperty="1,2,4" runat="server" />
```

The message error is: 
*Cannot create an object of type 'System.String[]' from its string representation '1,2,4' for the 'MyProperty' property.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to implement a [`TypeConvertor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typeconverter.aspx) for this.

These resources could help you with it:

1. [How to: Implement a Type Converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ayybcxe5.aspx)
2. [Passing int list as a parameter to a web user control](https://stackoverflow.com/q/251439/102112)
3. [Passing int array as parameter in web user control](https://stackoverflow.com/q/116797/102112)