# passing array as parameter in web user control

Tags: asp.net, arrays, user-controls

Is there a way to pass int array as a parameter to web user control. I found the same question in SO which was asked in 2008, so the person who asked was probably using .net 3.5 or something and the answer was not convincing [Passing int array as parameter in web user control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116797/passing-int-array-as-parameter-in-web-user-control). I am using .net 4.0. Is there a way to do it in the new version?

I want something like

`<user:control id="mycontrol" runat="server" myarray="1,2,3" />`

or from code behind

`mycontrol.myarray = arr; //where arr is int array`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will be able to do it from the code behind but I don't think it's possible to specify arrays from the markup. Just declare a property of array type in the user control declaration and make sure it's public.

Comment: thanks, will give it a shot. I guess i was forgetting the "public" part